# Best source code formatter for Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, code-formatting

I've been digging through Stack Overflow as well as a number of Google searches, and I cannot find a satisfactory code formatter for JavaScript.

I have found several related tools, such as syntax highlighters and pretty-printers, but I am looking for a tool that I can ideally create a wrapper for in Eclipse and simply run from the menu bar. Hence, if any Java-based ones are available, that is a big plus. Free and/or open-source is preferred as well.

I am looking for something that my development group can use to maintain a consistent code style.

**Edit:** Thanks to kRON for linking to the [format customizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351298/best-source-code-formatter-for-javascript#351310) page.

**Edit:** [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In one breath: [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3.html)! Yes, it's Java based and free (Eclipse, as standalone or plugin).

You can also [customize the formatting](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Customizing_your_formatting_preferences).

Comment: The link above results in 404 -- this looks like the current page http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3.html

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I've updated the link accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

This is by far the best I've come across: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Available as an online tool, or on the command-line using node.js or python.
[The source code is available](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify).

Comment: fast and quick solution. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you already use Eclipse, I recommend you to try [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration), you can install it as an Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 5):

- For Eclipse IDE you can use [JavaScript Code Formatter](https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/eclipse-formatter-profiles) based on [Goolge's Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)
- For IntelliJ IDEA you can use the same js code formatter xml file , but previously you have to install a special plugin [Eclipse Code Formatter Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=6546), which solves the problem of maintaining a common code style in team environments where both IDEA and Eclipse are used

Answer (score 3):

If you also need Java programming I can recommend '[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)'

It offers excellent JavaScript formatting and refactoring out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net). It's great for trying things out with Javascript. Built in JSLint & something called Tidy. Not sure whether that infers [jstidy](http://code.google.com/p/jstidy/) [Piotr Zalewa](http://piotr.zalewa.info/) is the guy who wrote it. May be worth giving him a Tweet [@zalun](http://twitter.com/zalun) to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notepad++, you can try jsminnpp plugin