# Javascript, any clean up tools written in javascript itself?

Tags: javascript

I'm basically looking for a javascript library that accepts an arbitrary string which may be valid javascript and returns a "cleaned up" version based on javascript indention rules.  It would be nice if the library also did css and html.

Barring that, if someone has an interesting idea for doing it from javascript I'd love to hear it.

Comment: [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: You might find the answers in this thread usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045241/what-is-a-good-stand-alone-javascript-formatter-for-fixing-missing-semicolons

Comment: *related* (duplicate?): [JavaScript beautifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier). It doesn't do HTML and CSS though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ has an identation function as well, for both js, css and html.

Comment: also, **JSLint** and **JSHint**

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://beautifier.io/ .

But you can also use node-beautifier in node js :P