# Are there any Mac OS code editors that support code auto-formatting (a.k.a. beautifying)?

Tags: macos, text-editor, autoformatting

So far I'm really impressed with [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/), but it doesn't seem to offer any auto-formatting (by which I'm spoiled by Visual Studio). Are there any general code editors for Mac that support this? Specifically I'm interested in PHP and JavaScript, but curious to know about any options that might exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found Dreamweaver to be a great development platform on the Mac for PHP and Javascript.  I'm not sure if you have access to it, but if it is a possibility, at least give it a test run.  It does code highlighting, etc. that makes it much easier to code.  The price, however, does make it a problem for most people.

In that case, you could try BBEdit.  I've heard good things from people who would know but I personally have not used it (I have Dreamweaver through my company).  It does auto-complete and a bunch of other nice things.  It only costs $99 so it isn't too bad.  Here is the link to the site:

http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/

Answer (score 1):

I like [TextMate](https://web.archive.org/web/20221208003521/https://macromates.com/). It’s powerful and inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a good one from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351298/best-source-code-formatter-for-javascript) answer, [Aptana Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20141028160346/http://aptana.org:80/). Looks like it's free/open-source, multi-platform, and supports code formatting for things like JavaScript and PHP.

I'll try it out and post back the results!

**Update:** While the app is okay and does offer some handy formatting, it's unfortunately clumsy and has some really annoying interface behavior (like code completion that won't go away and appears at the worst possible times) and a horrible options dialog, so it's not an ideal solution.