# Reformatting JavaScript/JScript code?

Tags: javascript, pretty-print

I've got a JScript error on my page. I know where the error's happening, but I'm attempting to decipher the JScript on that page (to figure out where it came from -- it's on an ASPX page, so any number of user controls could have injected it).

It'd be easier if it was indented properly. Are there any free JScript reformatters for Windows?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use Firebug or some similar debugging tool to actually *find* the problem, but, if you want to just format your JavaScript code, [here's a reformatter I found on Google](http://javascript.about.com/library/blformat.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio), its free and really good, and you can [customize your formatting preferences](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Customizing_your_formatting_preferences).

Answer (score 1):

How about if you just run Firebug, it will tell you what the error is and will take you to where it is.

Tools like phpDesigner (there's a free trial) have a code beautifier that will work on JavaScript, but nothing beats the good old TAB key (and shift tab to remove junk indention) :P

Answer (score 1):

Use **Visual Studio 2008**

1. Create a new Web-Form
2. Paste your js code in the **source**
3. select-all (`ctrl + a`)
4. right click to open the context-menu
5. Click on **Format Selection**

The js and html will then be formatted accordingly

Comment: Doesn't work for me (in VS2008 Developer). Doesn't work in a .JS file, or in a .ASPX file.

Comment: It works in an aspx page...I use it all the time actually
It also indents the code when you terminate a line with a ;