# Is there a windows utility similar to HTML Tidy for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, editor, code-formatting

I want to cleanup some javascript files and reformat them with nice indents, etc,
Are there recommendations for utilities to do this under Windows?

Comment: I used to do this with a little regex "script" - I'll see if I can dig that out

Comment: That would be interesting, please post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Beautify Javascript](http://elfz.laacz.lv/beautify/) is a good, simple option.

(Oops. Thought I grabbed the link for the app, not the home page.) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the online [JavaScript Tidy](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/JSTidy.html)

> Several attempts have been made to
>   produce programs to reformat code, but
>   these often fail to cope with
>   situations such as '{', '}' or ';'
>   characters inside strings, regular
>   expressions, or comments, so **virtually
>   all of them end up with broken code**.
>   However, browsers already have their
>   own parsers built in that deal with
>   all of these situations. **This script
>   hooks into the browser's own parser,
>   by wrapping the code in a function
>   then using the native toString method
>   to obtain the tidied code.** As a
>   result, it relies on the browser
>   producing a tidied output, which there
>   is no requirement for them to do. In
>   fact, it relies on the browser
>   decompiling to tidied code instead of
>   just retaining the original, which is
>   an expensive process in terms of
>   performance, and leads to extra
>   complexity when trying to make sure
>   the decompiled code still works, so
>   not all browsers choose to do it this
>   way.
>
> For best results, use Opera 9.2x- (not
>   9.5+), Safari or Konqueror on this page. It partially works in Firefox
>   (nested functions are not tidied,
>   meaning that most scripts you want to
>   tidy still end up unreadable), and
>   fails to reformat code in IE and iCab
>   3-. Since you can always keep a copy
>   of Opera 9.2 on your computer (as well
>   as whatever the current version is), I
>   recommend you use Opera, and keep a
>   copy of it around for use with JSTidy.

Comment: great site, i will have to give that a try for similar problems

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio you can open the Javascript document and press CTRL+K, CTRL+D to format the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

[This page on about.com](http://javascript.about.com/library/blformat.htm) has a tool where you paste in your script and it cleans it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

[GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) tidies up C-style languages.  Perhaps Javascript could be used as a subject as well.

Answer (score 0):

For offline use, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier#27343) to a similar question explains how to set up the code Jonathan suggested to run from a command line with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Answer (score 0):

Our [JavaScript Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/ECMAScriptFormatter.html) uses a language-precise parser to read the Javascript and then format the code.  It doesn't get confused by the contents of HTML, strings, or characters.  Does run on Windows.