# Is there a program that will auto format my javascript?

Tags: javascript, pretty-print

#### Duplicate:

> [Javascript Beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier)

---

Is there a way I can auto format my javascript so its readable?

I have a javascript file that is just one line but about a million columns white. I don't want to go through and tab through each function just so I can read it.

Anyone know of a program that will do this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: @hanesjw: yes, there are programs and websites that will do this for you - see the answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier

Comment: Try googling 'js beautifier' :)

Comment: If it's a duplicate, shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: @lothar: I voted to close. It takes 4 others to actually close it, but if i don't provide the link then poor hanesjw is left wondering why it's being voted on!

Answer (score 1):

On OS X use [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) with the JavaScript bundle.