# Match end of Javascript code statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to process/parse and alter some Javascript code, preferably in a regular expression if that's possible (open to suggestions). The purpose would be to insert a new code snippet after each statement in the JS.

**For example:**

*The original Javascript:*

```
while(true){

    Utils.log("hello world");
    Utils.sleep(1000);

}
```

*Code snippet that I would like to insert:*

```
checkPause();
```

*So the new code would look like this:*

```
while(true){

    checkPause();
    Utils.log("hello world");
    checkPause();
    Utils.sleep(1000);
    checkPause();

}
checkPause();
```

The example above is quite simple, but the real JS code could be more complex and could even be minified. The code could also miss out some semicolons `;`

Comment: I'm assuming this is for debugging purposes?

Comment: The term for this is "instrumentation", and this question has been asked before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843546/parse-javascript-to-instrument-code

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I'm building a program in C#, it makes use of the V8 engine & http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/ to run some scripts. I need the script to check if it should pause.

Comment: @user1816548 Thanks for the link, I'm checking.

Comment: This is not possible to do with a regex. Use a javascript parser for that.

Comment: Look at [jscoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

A very dirty way to do this would be to insert your snippet after every opening brace, closing brace, and semicolon. Like this:

```
 code.replace(/\;/g, '; checkPause(); ').replace(/\{/g, '{ checkPause(); ').replace(/\}/g, '} checkPause(); ')
```

A proper way would be to use a parser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to test more for my purpose but it seems to work. I have narrowed it down to `Regex.Replace(code, @"\;|\{|\}|\n", @"$0 checkPause();")` in C#.

Comment: Just be careful that your code doesn't include e.g. a = ";" :)