# Command line formatter for PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, code-formatting

Are there any command line (not interactive, not web-based) tools that will reformat (pretty-print) PHP and Javascript code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP_ Beautifier is very outdated! For a more modern approach try [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

Example command:
`php-cs-fixer fix --rules=@PSR2 path/to/php/src`

A second alternative is [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

Example command: `phpcbf --standard=PSR2 path/to/php/src`

Comment: As of 2024, `php-cs-fixer` only handles basic things like indentation.  If you have truly horrible code with things like inconsistent spacing around brackets, it won't fix that.

Answer (score 3):

For a PHP beautifier, you can also use this pear package [PHP_Beautyfier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/), which can either be called  from the command line or instantiated within your own PHP code. For the Javascript one instead, find an open discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier)

Comment: This is still beta, and hasn't been updated since 2010, with a number of unresolved bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article explaining how to build a [command-line JavaScript beautifier implemented in JavaScript](http://blog.shonzilla.com/post/1448821411/command-line-javascript-beautifier). The best part - it takes under 5 minutes to do it, YMMV.

Cheers!
Shonzilla