# Replacing / with TAB using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I need to replace a slash character with a tab to I can extract a directory name using awk.

```
/path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path
```

I tried doing this, but all it does is put a "t" at the from of my output.

```
sed -e 's/\//\t/g' filename
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to depend on the version of `sed`. Try `tr '/' '\t' < filename` and see what happens.

Comment: You don't need to replace `/` with `TAB` and feed it to `awk`. `awk` can simply do it on its own.

Comment: Come to think of it, how about `cut -f5 -d'/' < filename`?

Comment: The question is a mixture of a need and tentative solutions. The actual need seems to extract USEFUL_INFORMATION but it doesn't tell if e.g. there's always the same number of slashes before that, which changes the problem. Is replacing / with TAB part of a tentative solution... or the real question ? In the latter case there are related questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424126/replace-whitespaces-with-tabs-in-linux .

Comment: `gsed -e 's/\//\t/g' filename` since GNU `sed` understands `\t`. On Mac, install with `brew install`.

Answer (score 36):

First, you can use another character as the `s///` delimiter. The command

```
sed 's:ABC:DEF:g'
```

is equivalent for

```
sed 's/ABC/DEF/g'
```

It will make your command more readable because you'll not have to escape the slash.

Said that, some seds do not support character escaping such as `\t`. It happens to me a lot in Mac OS X, for example. My solution is to press Control+V and then the tab char:

```
sed 's:/:<Control+V><TAB character>:g'
```

The result in my machine is:

```
$ pwd
/Users/brandizzi/sandbox/demo/mydemo
$ pwd | sed 's:/:        :g'
    Users   brandizzi   sandbox demo    mydemo
```

However, if your intention is to put all path directories in awk variables `$1`, `$2` etc. just declare the slash to be the field separator with awk `-F` flag:

```
$ pwd
/Users/brandizzi/sandbox/demo/mydemo
$ pwd | awk -F / '{print $3 " " $5}'
brandizzi demo
```

Comment: Thanks for the: <Control+V><TAB character>  tip for Mac.

Comment: Ditto. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

Try `awk`:

```
awk  '{gsub("/","\t",$0); print;}' filename
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me on OS X

Answer (score 11):

**To replace / with TAB using sed**:

```
sed 's/\//\'$'\t/g' filename.txt
```

Generally, place \'$' before tab (\t) and newline(\n) characters. Works in bash.

**To extract the directory name:**

Personally, I'd use grok12's answer.

```
awk -F'/' '{print $5}' filename.txt
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct (most direct, using just `sed`) answer. I also use `^V^I` but don't like non-visible characters in maintained script files that some editors could mess up.

Comment: and allows to do things like `s/\//\'$'\t\t\n/g`

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer, for me, [here](http://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/sed-replace-a-tab-character-using-sed/). I have MacOSX so I used the Control+v followed by Control+i.

```
sed -e 's/\/[CTR+V][CTR+I]/g' filename
```

Comment: You can also use <Tab> instead of <Ctrl + I>! <Ctrl + V> tells the terminal to interpret the character literally instead of running one of the bound actions (e.g. Tab would usually try to autocomplete the current word, but this lets you insert a tab character directly)

Answer (score 1):

> awk -F '/' '{print $5}' your_file

This prints USEFUL_INFORMATION

It defines the field separator to be /.  Note that since your strings start with a / the first field is null so your field counts will be one more than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put double quote(" ") around instead of single quote(' ') as shown in the following command.

`sed -i "s/\//\\t/g" filename`

Generally we use double quotes(" ") with the **sed** when we are dealing with the special characters.

As in your case you haven't escaped the **\** in TAB character(\t).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`` `printf "\t"` ``](http://mdoc.su/-/printf.1) within [`sed`](http://mdoc.su/-/sed.1):

```
sh -c 'echo test1 test2 | sed -E "s#(.*) (.*)#\2`printf "\t"`\1#g"'
```

The output is:

```
test2   test1
```

---

Here's to show it works for your own example:

```
sh -c 'echo /path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path | sed "s#/#`printf "\t"`#g"'
```

Output:

```
path    to  some    USEFUL_INFORMATION  in  some    path
```

Comment: Closest answer to what [shellcheck suggest](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1012). [Great related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145385/209677),

Answer (score 0):

Use + as delimiters
    `sed -e 's+/+\t+g`'

```
echo 'path/to/something' | sed -e 's+/+\t+g'

// path     to     something
```

**Edit:**
a simpler way to extract the path of a file:

```
dirname /path/to/file.txt
#output /path/to
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `dirname`and `basename`

```
$ dirname /path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path
/path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some

$ basename /path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path
path
```

awk can handle any separator, e.g. `/`:

```
$ echo /path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path | awk -F"/" '{print $5}'
USEFUL_INFORMATION
```

Answer (score 0):

First as the others suggested, use another character as a delimiter. Second, use `$'\t'` **outside** of the quotes. Example with `;` as a delimiter:

```
$ echo "/path/to/some/USEFUL_INFORMATION/in/some/path" | sed -e 's;/;'$'\t'';g'
path    to  some    USEFUL_INFORMATION  in  some    path
```

Comment: What version of sed is this running on what *NIX platform?