# Is it possible to replace a newline AND another character with a single tab using sed?

Tags: sed

I have to replace a `]\n` with a `\t` using `sed`, but I have no idea how to do it. can anybody help me?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Why do you "have to" use sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the virtual machine that is `sed` works a certain way, and the way that it works doesn't make it easy to:

- replace newlines.  See [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) for why that is.
- replace anything with a tab, See [Replacing / with TAB using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363328/replacing-with-tab-using-sed) for more about that.

Still, it *can* be done:

```
printf 'foo]\nbar\n' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\]\n/ \'$'\t/g'
```

Output:

```
foo     bar
```