# XQuery and Zorba: Setting indent to add a tab character instead of two spaces

Tags: html, xquery, space, indentation, zorba

I'm using the

```
--indent, -i
Indent output.
```

command line argument of Zorba XQuery 2.1 to ident the html output of my XQuery.

Is there any option that can be set so the indenting will be done using a tab character instead of two spaces?

Thank you

Comment: As a feature request for zorba, you can add a bug report for it and mark it as "wishlist". https://bugs.launchpad.net/zorba/+filebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not possible. How do you use Zorba. From unix terminal? If yes, you can use a unix command:

[Replace whitespaces with tabs in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424126/replace-whitespaces-with-tabs-in-linux)

Comment: I'm using it from Windows 7, from a batch file. But I'm using fart-it.sourceforge.net to replace the white spaces with tabs.