# How do I replace four spaces by one tab in a big python codebase?

Tags: python, tabs, coding-style, space

I have downloaded a python code and would like to edit it. The problem is that I used to use tabs to make indents but file use four spaces instead and if a combination of spaces and tabs is used, visually it looks fine, but the code generate errors.

My question is if there is a simple way to replace spaces by tabs?

Comment: although expand will not convert spaces to tabs? also it will convert all tabs, not just leading whitespace. But a nice tool nonetheless.

Comment: unexpand would be the tool that converts spaces to tabs

Comment: apparently unexpand --first-only --tabs=4 would also do the trick .

Answer (score 3):

get an editor that understands simulated tabs. then it will simulate tabs using 4 spaces. Most editors can do this nowadays. They feel just like tabs but are spaces..

Comment: also most editors which understand this, can also "format code" to some specification. including changing indent style. get a good editor or an IDE

Answer (score 2):

Use `reindent.py`.  It should be in tools/scripts on your system.  In some cases it may not be installed by default, and require the addition of an extra package, ex: python-examples or python-tools.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Use an editor that can be configured to indent with tabs or spaces and reconfigure it as needed. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), [GEdit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) or any other even moderately serious code editor can do this.

   Additionally, if your editor supports it, do turn on displaying of the initial whitespace.
2. On linuxes/unices you have multiple command line tools to help you with the conversion. Just check out answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424126/replace-whitespaces-with-tabs-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

In Vim there is command retab. I'm have that line in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F7> :set noexpandtab!<CR>
```

So, any time i need to revert from tabs to spaces or vice versa, i press F7 and call command in vim:

```
:retab!
```

Very useful plugin if you use vim - **spacehi.vim**. This plugin will highlight tabs and trailing spaces on a line, with the ability to toggle the highlighting on and off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU/Linux or MacOSX with bash then you can use this in command line:

```
find . -type f -name '*.py' | while read file; do
     grep '    ' $file > /dev/null && sed -ie 's/    /\t/g' $file
done
```