# Properly formatting JavaScript in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indentation, pretty-print

How can I automatically format JavaScript properly?

As an example, this:

```
(function(){(function(){alert('whatever')})()})()
```

Should become:

```
(function(){
    (function(){
        alert('whatever')
    })()
})()
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net has a "tidyup" option - maybe it's open source based?

Comment: Have you tried [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)?

Comment: @Cameron turns out that's the one that jsfiddle uses

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Beautifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org), you can find the source code at [github](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify).

Comment: Python based?  The one I saw is written in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://jsbeautifier.org/ - it's the same one used by [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) on their "Tidy Up" button where you can try it out.