# Java Code beautifier/formatter library with PHP, JavaScript support

Tags: java, coding-style, formatting, code-generation

I'm searching a java library that formats/beautifies a given source code snippet. The library should support at least PHP and JavaScript source files.

The reason why i'm searching this is because the code that i generate with my Java application from a REST API description looks not to appealing. I am generating the source files with FreeMarker template engine and i don't want to implement all the formatting logic in the template files. It should be possible that way, but it makes the template files a lot harder to maintain.

Comment: Do you want to do it as part of the build process or is it OK if you run this beautifier at will?

Comment: It should be sufficient to run the beautifier as a build process.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT. After reading your comment, I would say: invoke the external beautifier from within you build script.

For Javascript, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/what-javascript-code-beautifier-can-i-use-via-the-command-line-on-windows-and-li) may help. Disclosure: I'm the coauthor of [JSBeautifier](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify) described in the answer (actually, I work on the Python modules). Essentially, use `rhino` as the interpreter for JSBeautifier.

For PHP, a quick search brought [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) to my attention.